# How can I get coveralls to ignore code from gems my gem has as dependencies?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, code-coverage, coveralls

I've made a small gem ([SmsSafe](https://github.com/dmagliola/sms_safe)), and it currently has 100% code coverage (according to SimpleCov).

However, according to Coveralls, it only has 41% coverage ([report here](https://coveralls.io/r/dmagliola/sms_safe?branch=master)).

The reason for that difference seems to be that coveralls is taking the code from my gem's dependencies as part of my code, and complaining that those aren't covered...

I haven't seem it do this in any other gems I've looked into, and I haven't seem any special coveralls configuration in those gems' codebases...

The way I'm calling coveralls is by having this in my Rakefile:

```
require 'coveralls/rake/task'
Coveralls::RakeTask.new
task :test_with_coveralls => ["test", "coveralls:push"]
```

and by having Travis evecute "test_with_coveralls":

```
script: bundle exec rake test_with_coveralls
```

Which is the right way of adding it [according to their docs](https://coveralls.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/201769485-Ruby-Rails)

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two steps necessary.

On the one hand, following Coveralls documentation, set the SimpleCov formatter to be Coveralls:

```
require "simplecov"
require "coveralls"
SimpleCov.formatter = SimpleCov::Formatter::MultiFormatter[
    SimpleCov::Formatter::HTMLFormatter,
    Coveralls::SimpleCov::Formatter
]
```

or

```
SimpleCov.formatter = Coveralls::SimpleCov::Formatter
```

That doesn't fix the issue, though, this is the undocumented part:

When calling SimpleCov.start, make sure to filter out the "/gemfiles/vendor" directory

```
SimpleCov.start do
    add_filter "/gemfiles/vendor"
end
```

Comment: Excellent, that just did it! Updated your response a bit to apply more to my issue, for future askers. Thank you!!